# how to compile qgis-1.8.0 on ubuntu

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-plugins, mapserver, pyqgis

i have downloaded qgis-1.8.0.tar.bz2 and I want to install it on my linux computer(12.04 LTS). How can I perform it please?

I do it because I am desperate with Qgis 2.0.1 Dufour on ubuntu 12.04, when I wan to create a mapfile (I have many errors with RT-mapserver).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing with apt-get an specific version?

`sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>`

You can also try using Synaptic package manager, you have an option to choose the version. I think i would be simpler than compiling.